# Slow D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile relatively CrystalDiskMark speed

Tags: file, networking, storage, directx-11

I'm working on a DirectX 11 based C++ application. I measured the speed of the D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile function I use in a single thread, it is 0.5 megabytes per second. I assume that most of the time is spent reading files - this function has as inputs argument many small files from the disk. The files are located on local network storage, the file transfer to which is 5 megabytes per second according CrystallDiskMark (4kB blocks, 1 thread, random access). Why is there such a difference between measurements in my progrram and CrystallDiskMark? Is there a possibility to increase the speed of D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile?

I've tried to use WinAPI CreateFile and ReadFile function with the goal to create shader resource view from memory, but CreateFile is working slow as well.

Comment: As stated in the doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3dx11createshaderresourceviewfromfile, you should instead use DirectXTK or DirectXTex (load the file and CreateShaderResourceView in two steps, which will also tell you where time is really spent)